# Add remove link to ListView - how to refer outer anonymous class from inner anonymous class

Tags: java, wicket

Wicket ListView provide removeLink to add with ListItem. The implementation of the removeLink method in the source of ListView class is:

```
public final Link removeLink(final String id, final ListItem item)
{
    return new Link(id)
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link#onClick()
         */
        public void onClick()
        {
            addStateChange(new Change()
            {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                final int oldIndex = getList().indexOf(item.getModelObject());
                final Object removedObject = item.getModelObject();

                public void undo()
                {
                    getList().add(oldIndex, removedObject);
                }

            });

            item.modelChanging();

            // Remove item and invalidate listView
            getList().remove(item.getModelObject());

            ListView.this.modelChanged();
            ListView.this.removeAll();
        }
    };
}
```

Now if I add a Link to the ListItem and Override the onClick() method as above and add some more functionality to it, how can I redefine this snippet :

```
ListView.this.modelChanged();
ListView.this.removeAll();
```

As instantiation of ListView object is done by Anonymous Class of ListView and same for the Link.

```
add(new ListView("listId", list) {
    protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
         item.add(new Link("linkId") {
             public void onClick() {
                 // how can I define
                 // ListView.this.modelChanged();
                 // ListView.this.removeAll();
                 // here?
             }
         });
    }
});
```

That is how to refer outer anonymous class from inner anonymous class? Is calling method of anonymous outer class (although it is inner) from anonymous inner class of that outer class in general? Is is possible in Java?

Comment: Did you try that? Did it compile?

Comment: @Ravi Wallau no it didn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Component.findParent(class)`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#findParent%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
ListView<?> listView = findParent(ListView.class);
listView.modelChanged();
listView.removeAll();
```

Or you could just call `super.onClick()` in your `onClick()` method.

Comment: I tried this.getParent() in the onClick() method. But it fails. And link extend AbstractLink which further extends WebMarkupContainer, there is no onClick() method in the super (s). Although onClick() of Link is abstract. Isn't it? How can I call super.onClick()? What about calling method of anonymous outer class (although it is inner) from anonymous inner class of that outer class in general? Is is possible in Java?

Comment: @Tapas a) what does "it fails" mean? This is a standard method, and it always works b) about super, my mistake, I thought you were overrriding the removeLink()

Comment: 1) sorry my fault. Because I tried this.getParent() which was returning ListItem, so now I did (ListView) this.getParent().getParent() and it worked. Also (ListView) this.findParent(ListView.class) worked fine. So both of them worked. Thanks. 2) I have a question regarding the code snippet I gave in my first post. What is the need to call listView.removeAll(). After adding stateChange to Link, we invoked ListItem.modelChanging(), then remove the item and called modelChanged(), what is the use of removeAll()? 3) What made the page reloading? Thank you.

Comment: @Tapas please: no questions in comments. ask a new question

Answer (score 2):

I believe the code below will work - declared variables are accessible from the inner class as long as they are declared final, so you can declare a variable that holds the ListView instance and use it from your inner class, as I did in the example below. Please note that I didn't compile this code, but I see no reason for it not to work. Just remember that the variable must be declared final.

```
add(new ListView("listId", list) {
    protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
         final ListView lv = this;
         item.add(new Link("linkId") {
             public void onClick() {
                 lv.modelChange();
                 lv.removeAll();
             }
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. Your provided solution worked perfectly. So I guess by this way in general we can call method of outer anonymous class from inner anonymous class! Isn't it?

Comment: If you have the option of declaring the variable like I had then yes, that is a valid way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: don't use nested anonymous classes. They're an absolute nightmare to read and to maintain anyway. As a rule of thumb, if your class is going to have more than two methods or more than five lines of code in the method bodies, it is better to make it a proper, named class.

Comment: That is sound advise in many cases, but impractical with Wicket. The behavior of simple components, (like a text placeholder or form component) are often defined by overriding methods from parent classes.  If you were to create a proper class for each of these you'd have dozens of classes for even simple pages.

Comment: I use anonymous inner class in Swing too. And I love to use it.

Comment: I agree that anonymous classes shouldn't be over-used, but a listener-based framework like wicket becomes a nightmare with 100s of trivial classes without them

Comment: @perilandmishap Note that I didn't say on every occasion and I didn't say you should use top level classes. There's indeed some advantage of an anonymous inner class over a named inner class, but all that is lost the moment you try to do non-trivial things.